# Is there way to insert selected code into template twice?

Tags: delphi, templates

I've created a template in Delphi XE to use it often

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<codetemplate   xmlns="http://schemas.borland.com/Delphi/2005/codetemplates"
                version="1.0.0">
    <template name="noado" surround="true" invoke="manual">
        <description>
            no ado
        </description>
        <author>
            BVA
        </author>
        <code language="Delphi" delimiter="|"><![CDATA[{$ifndef no_ado}
|selected||*||end|
{$endif}]]>
        </code>
    </template>
</codetemplate>
```

Now it looks like this

**{$ifndef no_ado}

|selected|

{$endif}**

I want to simplify my work by making something like this

**{$ifndef no_ado} 

|selected| overload; deprecated 'Use AppData';

{$endif}

|selected| overload;

//------------------------------------------**

Comment: I assume you've tried the obvious solution already? Note that when no_ado isn't defined, your code won't compile because it will have duplicate declarations. Maybe you should just put the deprecation clause by itself in the conditional block: `{$ifndef no_ado} deprecated 'Use AppData';{$endif}`

Comment: Yes, I know it, and that's what I need. I just want to simplify my work by using template on selected function:
`function name_function(params);`
And when template applies, I want to receive this:
`{$ifndef no_ado}
function name_function(params); overload; deprecated 'Use AppData';
{$endif}
function name_function(params); overload;
//------------------------------------------
`

Comment: Yes, I understand that's what you want the template to generate for you. What I don't understand is *why*. It's invalid code because it declares the same function twice.

Comment: Yes this code is invalid at first time. But I just want template to make current overloaded function deprecated and make a copy of declaration to change its parameter types so new declaration will differ from previous that is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
//--------------------------------------1 Template

```
<codetemplate   xmlns="http://schemas.borland.com/Delphi/2005/codetemplates"
                version="1.0.0">
    <template name="noado" surround="true" invoke="manual">
        <description>
            no ado
        </description>
        <author>
            BVA
        </author>
        <code language="Delphi" delimiter="|"><![CDATA[{$ifndef no_ado}
|selected| overload; deprecated {$IF CompilerVersion > 21}'Use AppData'{$IFEND};
{$endif}
|end| overload;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------]]>
        </code>
    </template>
</codetemplate>
```

//--------------------------------------2Template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<codetemplate   xmlns="http://schemas.borland.com/Delphi/2005/codetemplates"
                version="1.0.0">
    <template name="noado_func" surround="true" invoke="manual">
        <description>
            no ado
        </description>
        <author>
            BVA
        </author>
        <code language="Delphi" delimiter="|"><![CDATA[{$ifndef no_ado}
|selected|
{$endif}
|end|
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------]]>
        </code>
    </template>
</codetemplate>
```

This is how to use the templates. 
First template is used to define function in Interface
1) Select and copy function definition: function NameFunc(params);
2) Use template
3) The cursor now is at the beginning of the line, so just paste copied code

Second template is used for body of the function:
1) Select and copy body of the function
2) Use template
3) Press up key, then press down key (or vice versa), so the cursor will be set behind the block
4) Paste copied code

This let me do all of the changes 3 times faster...